# Jsonpath query nested objects

Tags: json, jsonpath

I've got this this json data that I want to look up a certain value from with a query:

http://pastebin.com/Vf59Cf9Q

I want to find description == "chassis" in this path:

```
$.entries..nestedStats.entries..nestedStats.entries.type
```

However, I just can't get it to work.

Tried these two alternatives, but no luck:

```
$.entries..nestedStats.entries..nestedStats.entries[?(@.type.description == 'chassis')]
$.entries..nestedStats.entries..nestedStats.entries.type[?(@.description == 'chassis')]
```

Have tried this on these sites:

- http://jsonpath.com/
- https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/

Any help would be appreciated!

/Patrik

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick:

```
$.entries.*.nestedStats.entries.*.nestedStats.entries.type[?(@ == "chassis")
```